# How to create chapter style like this

Tags: chapters

I want to have this chapter style in my book. Can anyone tell me the LaTeX code for this

[image]

Comment: `\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}`

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends